# Using Cypress.io to retrieve verification code from message sent to Google Number/Inbox

Tags: javascript, google-api, gmail-api, cypress

My workplace is trying to use Cypress testing to validate user login/signup with a Google account that has inbox and a phone number associated with this account. So far, we're using PostMan and having our developers create projects to configure Gmail API and tokens. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of retrieving the emails/codes received with a Cypress or other js library/snippet that would streamline our testing.
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked into the [Gmail Api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs)? You could sign up, get your credentials/token via the Google Dev console.

Cypress have a cy.task ability to perform node functions. You could query the gmail account with that..